# Python - Skip *args and **kwargs

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I'm not really a Python expert so I'm kinda stuck with this weird situation.

Using wxPython, I'm trying to create a child Panel with my Window class as it's parent. For testing purposes I've created a new function which should add a simple Panel with a button.

In Visual Studio I can see that when creating the new Panel, instead of providing parameters for the wx.Panel, it's only expecting *args and **kwargs.

How do I get around that and provide needed params?

To give you a better idea what I'm talking about, see this 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiRe3.png).
I'd like to input the "parent" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment your post I will use this reply not to solve your question but to explain what does *args and **kwargs.

As far as I know, both arguments are used to pass an undeterminated number of arguments so they will be stored in a list ( args ) or in a dictionary ( kwargs ). So using those arguments you're able to loop over all parameters.

The needed params you have to provide to that function I have no idea, try looking the official documentation, surely there you'll find the arguments you need to pass to the function

Comment: I found the parameters you need doing a quick search in google: See https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Panel.html

Comment: You can pass the empty constructor or Panel(parent, id=ID_ANY, pos=DefaultPosition, size=DefaultSize,
      style=TAB_TRAVERSAL, name=PanelNameStr)